# need a regex to eliminate the ,\r\n but leave values intact. in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need a regex that will reformat, for example,

```
[
    0,
    38,
    255,
    255
          ],
```

into 
`[0, 38, 255,255],` but leave all the values intact, without disturbing any other code with a ,r\n\ sequence. Is it possible, and if so, could I get some help? below is some sample code. I have already formatted the [0, 0, 0, 0]'s correctly, but when the values are different every time, it's a lot harder to make a working regex. I have a sample of my code below, a tiny snippet of the whole.

```
      "value": [
0,
38,
255,
255
      ],
      "comment": "bright blue, entrance coupler",
      "connector": true,
      "connector-value": [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      "value": [
0,
255,
186,
255
      ],
      "comment": "bright aqua, water coupler",
      "connector": true,
      "connector-value": [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      "value": [
32,
32,
32,
255
```

Comment: did you wanna space before the last `255`?

Comment: Do you have always four values?

Comment: notepad++ doesn't do multi-line regex, M$ word does and so does visual studio, sublime text, and a lot of other editors.

Comment: @abc123: Where have you seen that?

Comment: @M42 on all the previous stackoverflow questions https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=notepad%2B%2B+multiline+regex+bug

Comment: @abc123: Have you read the answers? I'm using Npp for years now and I can say it works with multiline regex or I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: @abc123 Indeed using it for years and I formatted incorrect CSV-files with it stretching hundreds of newlines, with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have always four values, you could do:

Find what: `\[\s+(\d+),\s+(\d+),\s+(\d+),\s+(\d+)\s+\]`
Replace with: `[$1,$2,$3,$4]`

Comment: worked spectacularly, and was the easiest to use of all the answers. now I can finally get this mod updated for Starbound's new format. thanks! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

`(?s)\r?\n\s*(?=(?:(?!\}|\{|\]|\[).)*+(?:\]|$))`

and replace with nothing (or a space if you want the elements spaced out)

Make sure that the . matches newline checkbox is on (but the (?s) at the beginning of the expression should force that).

using your snippet, this expression returns:

```
  "value": [0,38,255,255],
  "comment": "bright blue, entrance coupler",
  "connector": true,
  "connector-value": [0, 0, 0, 0]
},
{
  "value": [0,255,186,255],
  "comment": "bright aqua, water coupler",
  "connector": true,
  "connector-value": [0, 0, 0, 0]
},
{
  "value": [32,32,32,255
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
 ([ \t]+)?(.*)?[\r\n]+
```

replace with `$2` in Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

```
\s(?=[^\[]*\])
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/3